# nkdagility VSTS Migration Tool

Tags: azure-devops

This question comes from the ever so popular "Crud, I can't find my documentation!"  Lol

So, last summer I started a project of migrating all of our Azure DevOps Projects within our organization into a single master project using the VSTS Migration Tool from nkdagility.  Due to some high priority projects that came up due to Covid and the CARES act, I ended having to put that project on hold, but now we are ready to start back up and I, for the life of me, can not find the command to run the actual migration.

Now, I have the config file created, so I don't need to run migration -init, but what is the command to run that migration with the configuration.json file that was created with the init command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the command to run that migration with the configuration.json file that was created with the init command?

You could navigate to the migration tool path and run the following command:

```
migration.exe execute --config configuration.json
```

Then the migration process will execute